# How to get Suggested Country & Reach for Page in Lookalike Audience?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I have a query for Lookalike Audience.

When i create a Lookalike Audience from Facebook (or power editor) after selecting a page I get a Country automatically selected (after some inspection i found out that FB returns & selected the "suggested_country" for that)

```
lookalike/suggested_country/?origin_audience_id=xxx
```

Is there any api call for getting the same in Ads API?

Also as the Reach changes as per country selection so how to get that number from Ads API ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no public API to retrieve the suggested country.